# How do I test classes involving Database and Exchange Server Access?

Tags: .net, database, web-services, unit-testing, testing

I just finished a tutorial for test driven development in c# with Nunit.
I now want to use unit tests for my new project, but i have difficulties writing tests.
How do I best write unit tests for classes involving Database or web-service access?
Can someone give me some classes/unit-tests examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Design an interface wrapping the functionality of calling db, sending email, ...
- Write an implementation of your class and load the this class in the dependent class using DI
- Use a Mock framework to create a Mock object and set expectations on it in your unit test.

Here is a sample pseudo-code (Mock generator used here is **Moq** framework):

```
interface IEmailer
{
    void Send(Email email);
}

class RealEmailer : IEmailer
{
    public void Send(Email email)
    {
        // send
    }
}

class UsesEmailer
{
    private IEmailer _emailer;

    public UsesEmailer(IEmailer emailer)
    {
        _emailer = emailer;
    }


    public foo(Email email)
    {
        // does other stuff
        // ...
        // now sends email
        _emailer.Send(email);
    }

}

class MyUnitTest
{
    [Test]
    public Test_foo()
    {
        Mock<IEmailer> mock = new Mock<IEmailer>();
        Email m = new Email();
        mock.Expect(e => e.Send(It.Is<Email>(m)));
        UsesEmailer u = new UsesEmailer(mock.Object);
        u.Send(m);
        mock.Verify();
    }

}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Now if you are testing `RealEmailer`, there are a few ways but basically you will have to setup the test to send you en email and you check in the . This is not quite a unit test since you are not only testing your code but the configuration, network, exchange server, ... in fact if you make `RealEmailer` small having little code, you can skip writing unit  test for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what does DI mean?

Comment: It is Dependency injection. You can use NInject, Windsor Castle, StructureMap, Spring.NET or Unity. I use Windsor.

Comment: Absolutely, in fact I do it. One is unit testing framework, the other is mocking framework.

Comment: Don't you need an assert statement in a test? Does Nunit recognize the verify method of the mock?

Comment: Sure, you would have your normal asserts. But in order to test `UsesEmailer` has called `Emailer` with correct parameters, you use mocks. And no, NUnit would not know.

Comment: How do i run thist test, when Nunit doesn't recognize the verify method. How do i see if it passed or not?

Comment: Sorry, it is VerifyAll() in Moq.